# Jackson cannot parse List<Long>

Tags: java, spring, jackson

Jackson parses `List<Long>` as `List<Integer>` and hence I get a `ClassCastException`. One of the solutions would be take the parameters as a `List<String>` but I don't want to do this. Could someone suggest me an alternative?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/device/deleteNote", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteNotification(@RequestBody ArrayList<Long> notificationIdListParam) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Could you show JSON String which you receive?

Comment: its a simple JSON list:
`[234863, 907123, 73673]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
final static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

final List<Obj> instance = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Obj>>(){});
```